# PHP MYSQL finding row number/rank from table with order by clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, row, rank

This has been doing my head in for hours now. It seems so simple but i just cant find the answers.

Basically I have a MYSQL table of the following example data, NOTE there are other columns but are not necessary for this question.

```
id | x  | y  
1  | 50 | 3
2  | 40 | 1
3  | 50 | 0
4  | 50 | 1
5  | 40 | 2
```

I want to order the table by x DESC and secondly y DESC. So I have this:

```
SELECT id, x, y FROM table_name ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC
```

Hopefully resulting in this:

```
id | x  | y  
1  | 50 | 3
4  | 50 | 1
3  | 50 | 0
5  | 40 | 2
2  | 40 | 1
```

Then given a specific id stored in a variable, I want to be able to find what row number its found in given the query. ie Find where it is ranked amongst the other rows.

I know there is a RANK and DENSE_RANK, if I need to use either I need RANK. But if using that's not the best solution, or how to use RANK please help.


For the above data if my id variable $id = 4, it's rank would be 2 as it is sorted second.
And i need this value returned as a variable. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql rank function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not support window/analytic functions.  You can emulate it using variables or complicated subqueries.  In your case, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT id, x, y, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank
FROM table_name cross join
     (select @rn := 0) const
ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the result for a given value, you can count the number of rows using an aggregation query:

```
select count(*)
from table_name t cross join
     (select t.*
      from table_name
      where id = $id
     ) id
where t.x > id.x or (t.x = id.x and t.y >= id.y)
```

EDIT II:

To use the first query to get a single id, put it in a subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT id, x, y, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rank
      FROM table_name cross join
           (select @rn := 0) const
      ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC
     ) t
where id = $id;
```

Comment: Your first example spits out a table of results exactly what Im after, but how do I then query that to find the row where $id = id and get that rows rank value. Your second example didnt seem to work. Thanks

Comment: You sir are a genius, thanks a lot for your help! If you're ever in Australia I'll buy you a beer :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple count should do the trick:

```
SELECT count(1)+1 FROM table_name WHERE x < ? or (x = ? and y > ?)
```

Where the question marks should be filled with the value of the column x of the row with id = $id. The +1 is because it counts the rows above the record, meaning that the rank = count+1.